# Most elegant way to execute a AWS lambda function with preloaded parameters on a specific time

Tags: scheduling, lambda, postgres, aws

I am looking for the following workflow:

- Add an entry to a table of my Postgres database with a `end_date` and `state` (with the following values: `active` or `done`) columns.
- Execute a lambda at the exact `end_date` value to update the `state` of this specific entry from `active` to `done`

The only ressources I found on Google about how scheduling a lambda function was for repetitive execution but I'm looking for single execution at specific date and time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share what you found on Google? It may improve the answer to show how to make a minor change instead of creating a whole new example?

Comment: How many entries in the database are we talking about?  The right answer for 20 records won't be the right answer for 20,000 or 20 million.

Comment: Also, how 'exact' do you need to be?  Within a couple of hours? a couple of minutes?  no more than 10 milliseconds from the `end_date`?

Comment: @JeffO Here is what I found: https://alestic.com/2015/05/aws-lambda-recurring-schedule/ Clearly after few more readings, I think the correct approach is to execute a lambda recurrently and check if I need to switch the status from `active` to `done` on all the rows of the table that are marked as `active`

Comment: @DanPichelman We're talking about few hundreds (maybe few thousands in a couple of months) entries in the table and the exactitude span should be between minutes and hours.

Answer (score -2):

You can schedule a lambda function to run as a crontab entry, and in the crontab entry set the exact date/time with no repetition.

Comment: How does this execute on the exact end date? Assuming there's more than one unique value across all records.